# Installing a Windows Service -Setup.exe fails

Tags: c#, visual-studio

There is a weird issue I am facing. I created my first windows service looking through various blogs and tutorials.
Then created setup for that adding installer etc. It works fine while installing , un-installing via Visual Studio but it fails when i deploy it .

```
Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * Activation of C:\Users\bhuvint\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\CPNS Library\ServicePackage\CommonPushNotificationWindowsService.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
        + You cannot start application CommonPushNotificationWindowsService from this location because it is already installed from a different location.
        + You cannot start application CommonPushNotificationWindowsService from location file:///C:/Users/bhuvint/Documents/Visual%20Studio%202010/Projects/CPNS%20Library/ServicePackage/CommonPushNotificationWindowsService.application it is already installed from location file:///C:/inetpub/wwwroot/ServicePackage/CommonPushNotificationWindowsService.application. You can start it from location file:///C:/inetpub/wwwroot/ServicePackage/CommonPushNotificationWindowsService.application or you can uninstall it and reinstall it from location file:///C:/Users/bhuvint/Documents/Visual%20Studio%202010/Projects/CPNS%20Library/ServicePackage/CommonPushNotificationWindowsService.application.
```

I have already un-installed the service and trying to install it from the deployed service in the same pc to test. But it fails with above error. 
**I feel i have deployed the windows service the wrong way. Could you guys please suggest how to deploy a windows service ??** *(I have looked through net. All suggest building it and installing it from visual studios. But how to publish it is the thing which i need.)*

Please help asap.

Comment: Have you checked in services if it is indeed stopped and uninstalled

Comment: Have you checked services.msc (through Windows key + R) is the name of your service still in there? Then you probably have to remove it there first. Simple Google search will tell you how :)

Comment: @JohnnBlade and Gerald- Yes i have done that. It has indeed been uninstalled .

Comment: I advice to un install from control panel. When I do so it doesn't fail reinstalling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**STUPIDITY PERSONIFIED**

As i told i was deploying my service. So this published code had a "setup.exe" file to it. Now I had already created a setup project for the windows service , which i was using for the installing , uninstalling . And i din't know (These words needs courage !!) that msi file created is required to install the windows service. So as i got through the folder structure of the setup project. I came across the .msi file . And hence the problem got solved. The Main problem was :

- Me not knowing to use setup projects
- And I confused setup.exe with the published windows service with the setup of windows service.

***I am really sorry for stealing bandwidth off your precious time. Thanks to all for the valuable inputs.***

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you built the setup project before uninstalling the preovious service. In that case you can't use the new setup to uninstall the service, since the setup won't be the same and can't be able to access the service installed.

You should try to go to a previous version of your project and uninstall the service and for the future unistall the service each time you're building your setup project.

This happened to me several times.

Answer (score 0):

Run visual studio in debug mode, and in your properties of your service project goto tab build events in Post-Build event command line and add a -d so you can run your service without installing it, it will run as an console app

Comment: Its not that i want to run it without installing. I want to install it !

Answer (score 0):

The LocalService account acts as a non-privileged user on the local computer, and presents anonymous credentials to any remote server. Use the other accounts with caution, as they run with higher privileges and increase your risk of attacks from malicious code.

If your service application will not install correctly, check to make sure that the ServiceName property for the service class is set to the same value as is shown in the installer for that service. The value must be the same in both instances in order for your service to install correctly.
NoteNote

You can also look at the installation logs to get feedback on the installation process.

You should also check to determine whether you have another service with the same name already installed. Service names must be unique for installation to succeed.

Comment: Jodha - I have used it in my visual studio to install it and run it. It runs perfect without any issues but when i publish it then it starts showing up the error.

Comment: try to do with some old school type code write codes in between your lines to show or write messages for you so you can track the progress and then rid these all off.